# Reusing tags in Azure DevOps

Tags: git, azure-devops

I'm using Azure DevOps and have a mono-repo, meaning multiple projects are within the same repo. Because of this there are many commits which are completely unrelated and so makes it difficult to see all the commits related to one product.

When I'm viewing the history of a branch, I want to easily be able to see all the commits related to one product. My initial idea was to tag the commit during the build with the product name e.g. `AdminService` so then it shows up in the history with a nice easy to read name, but then found out the tag has to be unique so can't do this!

I could append the build ID to the tag name to make it unique if there's no other alternative but would like to see if there is some other way to filter commits and be able to view them easily. Is there an alternative to this?

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you add tags like : AdminService.1,AdminService.2,AdminService.3 ...... this will not be repeated

Comment: @HughLin-MSFT That's what I was thinking, using something like the BuildId variable to make it unique. Only reason I was seeing if there was another way is because that extra ID is extra information I'm not actually interested in, just extra 'clutter' so was seeing if there was a different way I hadn't thought of

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you go with a tag naming convention such as AdminService.1, .2, .3, etc, then you can easily filter on those tags and your search pattern might look like this (assuming git bash):

```
git tag -l AdminService* | xargs git show -s
```

But, perhaps you can just skip the tags and filter your log by specific directories of those projects. like this:

```
git log [directory-of-project]
```

Note you can navigate to the directory and do "git log ." too. This won't be perfect if your projects have pieces in different shared directories, but if that's the case then  tagging shared code likely wouldn't be clean either...

Comment: Didn't know about the `git log` command, that is really useful and will help with getting commits specific to a project!